Search by children, but only take the most recent child into account
Ok, so I'm trying to create a "versioned" information store in elastic search and I have a bit of a problem.
Specificaclly: I have an index with customer information. Normal details like name, various texts and such. Instead of updating this information whenever new information comes, I want to store a new version of it so I can do a search based on date. Like if I search for the most recent data, it'll just take the most recent version for every customer in my search, or I could search based on, let's say, a week ago, and so it needs to take into account the version that is the most recent up to the cutoff date of, in this case, a week ago
For example
Let's say I have a single customer (Bob) in my index that's been updated 3 times. Instead of dates, I'll use a day number here just to make it simpler:
So, Bob had his city updated three times on days 1,5,8:



Day
City




1
Chicago


5
NY


8
LA



So, now if I search for customers with city = LA, and indicate day 8, I should get a hit. I should also get a hit if I search for LA and indicate day 20 because Bob's most recent update up to day 20 was day 8, and is LA.
However, if I search for LA and indicate day 7, I should not get a hit because Bob's most recent update up to day 7 was day 5 which is NY. Nor should I get a hit for Chicago because though it was before day 7, there's a more recent version up to the cutoff.
In other words, when I indicate a day, it should behave as if I went back in time to that day and searched for the most recent data for every customer.
I'm thinking of perhaps adding a new document for every update, indicating some customer ID to group by and a date, or more likely a join relationship where I have a single main document for each customer (perhaps with information that doesn't change) and child records (eg customer_details) that are joined to it.
Having said that, I can't imagine how to actually query it. I somehow need to determine the most recent version for every customer AND THEN do my search based on it. The thing is, this system is going to have to do a lot of pretty complex text based searches and so simply using some sort of aggregation will not help. As I said, I should have access to the full force of ES's textual search abilities.
I tried asking chatGPT and it suggested this.
It doesn't really work because it still returns a hit, just shows the most recent version
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "update_timestamp": {
              "lte": "2024-09-25T00:00:00"  // Date filter
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": { "name": "Pete" }  // Searching for a specific name
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "persons": {
      "composite": {
        "sources": [
          { "person_id": { "terms": { "field": "person_id" } } }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_version": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              { "update_timestamp": { "order": "desc" } }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

